# Cannot establish XMPP server-to-server connection to gmail

Tags: g-suite, gmail, xmpp

My jabber-server fails to connect to gmail.com giving the error:
outgoing s2s stream myserver.com.ua->bot.talk.google.com closed: undefined-condition (myserver.com.ua is a Google Apps Domain with Talk service enabled.)

I am using the Prosody XMPP server. It works just fine with other jabber-servers I tested so far (e.g. jabber.ru). However, when some of my clients tries to add a gmail contact to his contact-list, the subscription request lasts forever, and the Prosody gives the following sequence of messages in its log:

```
Oct 21 22:57:16 s2sout95897f8   info    Beginning new connection attempt to gmail.com ([173.194.70.125]:5269) 
Oct 21 22:57:16 s2sout95897f8   info    sent dialback key on outgoing s2s stream 
Oct 21 22:57:16 s2sout95897f8   info    Session closed by remote with error: undefined-condition (myserver.com.ua is a Google Apps Domain with Talk service enabled.) 
Oct 21 22:57:16 s2sout95897f8   info    outgoing s2s stream myserver.com.ua->gmail.com closed: undefined-condition (myserver.com.ua is a Google Apps Domain with Talk service enabled.) 
Oct 21 22:57:16 s2sout95897f8   info    sending error replies for 2 queued stanzas because of failed outgoing connection to gmail.com
```

Here for the domain name of my server I use **myserver.com.ua**

I found a similar problem described in [this thread](http://logs.deltaz.org/talks@conference.qutim.org/2012/05/12.html), but there is no detailed description of the solution there.

As for the Google services, I did have a google account where I added the domain name under question to the Webmasters tools page. However, I deleted my account long ago, so now it is unclear, how any of the Google services can relate to my domain name.

So my question is: What is the real cause of this problem (my jabber-server configuration or imaginary Google account or something else) and how can I make my Prosody server connect to gmail.com jabber service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because google uses its internal way of communicating through jabber protocol.

If you disable Talk/Hangout in your google apps configuration, it will start to work (after few hours).

Comment: That's true. However, in my case it was even worse: I deleted my Google account, but the Google Apps record for my domain remained for some reason. So I had to contact Google's support team in order to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Google Apps, then you need to set some SRV records in your DNS.
You can use [this great tool](http://www.olark.com/gtalk/check_srv) to check if your domain's DNS is setup correctly, and if not - howto.

I ran a check on myserver.com.ua - The Jabber records were not found for that domain.

Comment: **1st:** This isn't an answer but a general statement and a link. -> Why not just post the type of SRV records you need to add and examples? You know: a real answer. **2nd:** It's now a broken link. Why you shouldn't post links generally unless it's a very specific answer and quality site. (Like a development sites KB) Didn't downvote(yet). Please fix though or remove.